# How can I generate notifications that data written via a FileStream is on the disk?

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io, filestream, fileshare

I would like to read a file after I have been notified that a certain amount of data has been written to it via another thread.
  My intial attempt was to create a Reactive Subject in my Writer class that calls OnNext after the Write to the BinaryWriter it is composed with. This BinaryWriter uses a FileStream.
This does not seem to work though. I am assuming I'm not guaranteed that the Write has been flushed.
 I'd rather not manually call flush.  Is there an existing way to do this?

Comment: Congratulations on asking the question number 5,000,000!

Comment: Does [File System Watcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) help?

Comment: Isn't there any prize for who asks the question numbered 5,000,000 or next 6,000,000 or ...? I think s/he should be worth receiving 100 points of reputation.

Comment: This can be duplicated answer according http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409492/read-from-a-growing-file-in-c

Comment: I don't believe FileSystemWatcher will give me the event granularity I'm looking for.  I don't think there is simple way to know when data written via FileStream will be available on disk. Currently, I am just polling the disk until I can invest in a higher level solution.

Answer (score 1):

At a broader level, you're asking about communications between threads.  There are a couple of ways to handle this depending upon your preferences and environment.

If you haven't already, look over POSIX threading [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) and [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).  Pay attention to the sections discussing conditional variables or semaphores.

The .NET framework has a [System Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/798axes2.aspx) library that's also worth looking over.  In particular, it has both a semaphore and a monitor class.  One or the other may be the solution you need in this case.

Finally, consider the [InotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx) interface and / or events.  In this context, it's an alternate route to signaling progress from the reader.

In general, I'd recommend having your writer thread throw an event changed notification or raise a semaphore after writing X bytes.  From there, the reader will either catch the event or watch for the semaphore and act accordingly.

I suspect the monitor class won't be as useful for you since the locking will likely prevent simultaneous access to the file.