# How to read from a constantly changing file a line at a timer tick and avoid delays in C#?

Tags: c#, plot, timer, filereader

I want to read line by line at a timer tick (`DispatcherTimer` with an ~0,1280 sec tick). The file gets updated every few miliseconds, since it is an ongoing written file, produced by another application. I would like to read a line at ~0,1280 (128 msec).

I assume 1 second delay at the start of the timer, to let the other application fill the text file with couple of lines.

After that I read a line and I also process it. Each line contains 64 numbers separated with a space. From this numbers I only need 20 which are placed at different positions = `index_of interest`. For that I use `line.Split()[index_of interest]` to return the desired numbers. And after that for each of those 20 numbers I apply a formula to compute a delta.

The numbers are stored withing a global variable which I than use to plot.

Here is the code:

```
 private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Read a line at a timer tick

        if ((linewl1 = filewl1.ReadLine()) != null && (linewl2=filewl2.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //There are 2 files that I need to read at the same time

                    var channel = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < DataAccessor.TotalNumberOfChannels.Length; i++)
                    {
                        //DataAccessor.TotalNumberOfChannels is an array of 0,1 and 1 indicates the index of interest

                        if (DataAccessor.TotalNumberOfChannels[i] == 1)
                        {
                            //I apply the methods that calculates the desired deltas

                            HemoDynamicData.RealTimeSimulationHbCalculation(
                                Convert.ToDouble(linewl1.Split()[i]) * Math.Pow(10, -7),
                                Convert.ToDouble(linewl2.Split()[i]) * Math.Pow(10, -7),
                                frames,
                                channel, i, new Coefficient(6.4, 5.75, 3.843707, 1.4865865, 1.798643, 2.526391, 3),
                                DataAccessor.UsedChannels);
                            channel++;
                        }

                        //Than I plot each of those 20x2 numbers 

                        Plotter.UpdateSimulatioPlot(Max, Min, frames, HemoDynamicData, DataAccessor);
                    }
                    frames++;
                }
    }
```

The timer is very slow. Is there another way that could allow me to do reading, processing and plotting within 0,1280 sec (128 msec)?

Comment: note that you are skipping two lines at `if (filewl1.ReadLine() != null && filewl2.ReadLine() != null)` . you read two lines but you dont store them inside variable so you just loose two lines here....

Comment: It's not the timer that is slow. The `tick` event couldn't keep up with the work that's being done. Time to `async`, maybe.

Comment: _0,1280 sec (1280 msec)_ ?

Comment: Indeed the computation of the `if` statement should be `if ((linewl1 = filewl1.ReadLine()) != null && (linewl2=filewl2.ReadLine()) != null)`

Comment: Thanks for remark, 128 msec in 0,1280 sec ( typo :) )

Comment: Note that synchronizing using a file is not the best.

Comment: I would like to show a real-time demo with data that a fNIRS device produces, and we cannot access this data directly. An aquisition software that comes with the device stores the raw data from the device. The only way to access it is  to look at the .txt files it produces.

Comment: I tried to put the emphasis on the fact that the file is updating within few seconds :)

Comment: A tip: don't use `DispatcherTimer`, do work without blocking UI (e.g. using `System.Timers.Timer`) and invoke calls to UI controls at the end. The bottleneck is the accessing file, so try to [concentrate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1409492/1997232) on that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the timer (`System.Timers.Timer`) as one suggested in a comment and also referred to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409492/read-from-a-growing-file-in-c).

Here is how I handle the timer:

```
public StreamReader file;
public StreamReader file2;
private string filewl1; //file paths
private string filewl2; //file paths

public void TimerStart()
{
     systemTimer.Interval = 128;
     systemTimer.Elapsed += systemTimer_Elapsed;
     systemTimer.Enabled = true;

     FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filewl1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            file = new StreamReader(fileStream);
     FileStream fileStream2 = File.Open(filewl2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
     file2 = new StreamReader(fileStream2);
}

private void systemTimer_Elapsed(Object source,  System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{ 
     if (!file.EndOfStream)
     {
          linewl1 = file.ReadLine();
          linewl2 = file2.ReadLine();  

          // ... do something 
     }
}
```

Thank you Sinatr!